# How to get 'Desktop' and 'Program Files' Name in current culture

Tags: c#-4.0, culture

I need to display the 'program files' and 'Desktop' path on a spanish PC.

I am trying

Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;

Which is returning the text 'Desktop'.
How do i get spanish text 'Escritorio' for desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of this variable is not having to worry about the exact name of the folder on the given computer. My Windows is in Spanish; if I write:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe",  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
```

My "escritorio" (`...\Escritorio`) is opened. If I write:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

I get `...\\Desktop`, but does not really matter (with my Windows version, I can access my desktop by typing either "Desktop" or "Escritorio"). If you use the first line (`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`) on any computer you will certainly access the given desktop, independently upon its language.